# Git: Know what commits were just pushed from a central repository perspective

Tags: git

Let us say we have two git controlled directories, central and central_clone, where central is a bare repository and central_clone is the clone of the bare repository. On a normal basis, if you on central_clone edit a file two times and register those updates via two different commits (name them HEAD and HEAD^^), when you push your changes the bare repository git would push both HEAD and HEAD^  to the central bare directory.

Is there a way from the central directory perspective to know what changed from the las commit on central repo to the just recently committed one?

I need this for an script that needs to diff what got pushed to the central directory, I normally did git diff HEAD HEAD^ but if git pushes all commits I would not see the real difference between what previously was on the central prior the push...

(the number of commits prior push can be more that two...)

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on reflog on the bare repository by setting the config `core.logAllRefUpdates` to `true`.

I think you should be able to glean pushes from that reflog. (But I haven't tried).